# Darken view as if disabled

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

How do you darken a view as if it were disabled/highlighted, preferably without using any additional views?

By view I mean a `UIView`, with all its children. I want to achieve the same effect of a disabled/highlighted `UIButton`.

Do not assume that the view is fully opaque.

Comment: With `view` do you mean the parent container with its all child components?

Comment: Seriously???? 11.9k reputation n this question???? o.O or i m getting this question wrong? :o

Comment: @HinataHyuga 11.9k-> means you cannot ask a question? He might be good at another language and is new to iOS? u never know...

Comment: @lakesh: Very true..I agree with that..

Comment: @0x7fffffff Yes. In fact, I have done it many times, usually by using another view. I wanted to read other idead.

Comment: @HinataHyuga Sometimes I ask questions about problems I've already solved to learn new ways of solving them. If no one replies, I post my solution. I don't do that immediately to avoid bias.

Comment: @lakesh I'm not new at iOS. I just wanted a different take on this problem.

Comment: @VishalK Yes, the whole enchilada.

Comment: @hpique Nice way to learn different approaches for any issue. :)

Comment: @HinataHyuga It is. I have learned quite a lot by asking questions about simple problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I'm currently playing with:

1. Create a black layer with opacity (`_highlightLayer`). This is similar to the "black view with alpha" approach.
2. Mask `_highlightLayer` with an non-opaque image of the original view.
3. Add the `_highlightLayer` to the view's layer.

Only the non-transparent pixels of the view will be darkened.

The code:

```
- (void)highlight
{
    // Black layer with opacity
    _highlightLayer = [CALayer layer];
    _highlightLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.layer.bounds.size.width, self.layer.bounds.size.height);
    _highlightLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _highlightLayer.opacity = 0.5;

    // Create an image from the view        
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *maskImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Create a mask layer for the black layer 
    CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
    maskLayer.contents = (__bridge id) maskImage.CGImage;
    maskLayer.frame = _highlightLayer.frame;

    _highlightLayer.mask = maskLayer;
    [self.layer addSublayer:_highlightLayer];
}
```

And then:

```
- (void)unhighlight
{
    [_highlightLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    _highlightLayer = nil;
}
```

Of course, this should only be used for small views.

Comment: This is actually precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

You have a UIButton *button1  and UIView *view1

You can disable a button and a view in this way:

```
[view1 setHidden:YES];
[button1 setEnabled:NO];
```

Enabling a button and a view can be done this way:

```
[view1 setHidden:NO];
[button1 setEnabled:YES];
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: That is not what I asked. BTW, you should disable buttons with `setEnabled`. And I'd say `setHidden` is preferred to `setAlpha` (unless you want a fade animation, in which case you need both).

Answer (score 0):

While this approach fails to meet your preference of not using additional views, simply adding a black view with alpha of 0.6 or so seems to achieve the effect, with the added benefit that you can use this new view to intercept UIEvents so that all the subviews are effectively disabled en masse.

You can even get graphically fancy and instead of just using a black background for the overlaid view, you can fill its background with a radial gradient to achieve the sort of spotlighted effect that happens in iOS when a popup view disables the view behind it...

Comment: Thanks. But this approach assumes that the UIView is fully opaque, which is a strong limitation.

Comment: Edited the original question to clarify.