# Darkening everything in UIViewController view except for a few UIImageViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I'm working in `iOS 6`.  Is there an easy way to darken (i.e. add a darker tint) to everything on a `UIViewController` screen except for a few select `UIImageViews`?

Like, the goal is to make the non-darkened images stand out.  The user clearly knows those are the only valid or selectable `UIImageViews` to tap -- and when the user taps a valid `UIImageView`, the screen would return to normal.

Just to clarify, I don't just want to vanish everything else, just darken it, like adding a transparent 0.5 alpha layer.

I looked here: [Darken view as if disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463230/darken-view-as-if-disabled) and it seems very relevant, except I'm not working on a single `UIImageView`, but a `UIViewController` that has `UIImageViews` as subviews.  And even if I run the masking code on every subview in my superview, it still wouldn't cover the entire screen, I think.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The easy, pragmatic solution would be to put a black view with 0.5 opacity between the images and the views behind the images.

Comment: That's perfect! But because the images I want to highlight will change from instance to instance, i would need to change which images are in front.  What is an easy way to do that?  Thanks!

Comment: So what do you think about adding the 0.5-opacity view over everything on the screen, and using `bringSubviewToFront:` on the UIImageViews and UIButtons I want to stand out?  That would effectively prevent touching the rest of the stuff, too, right?

Comment: Sounds like the right idea. You might need to have the black view swallow any touches it receives if there are touchable items not covered by the images or buttons you want to emphasize.

Comment: nickfalk: I'll accept your answer if you post it below. Only kink I still need to work out is making sure that all the bringSubviewToFront: calls don't end throwing my scene out of whack.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
blackView.alpha = 0.5;
[self.view addSubview:blackView];
for (UIImageView *imageViewToShow in self.view.subviews) {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageViewToShow];
}
```

If this causes problems, you might consider redesigning your code to keep the images inside a containerView of sorts. Then you can simply use `[self.view insertSubview:blackView belowSubview:containerView];` instead. Then you can manipulate the alpha and hidden aspects of the blackView whenever you feel like it. Heck, if your design warrants it you might add the blackView before any images have been created omitting the meed of the container view as well...

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5]; 
// This is a transparent black color.
```